# Pass state property via props (Vuex)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-props

I have a component that should display data from the store, but the component is reusable, so I would like to pass the name of the store module and property name via props, like so:

```html
<thingy module="module1" section="person">
```

Then, in the component:

```html
<template>
  <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
import get from 'lodash.get';

export default {
  props: [
    'module',
    'section',
  ],
  computed: mapState(this.module, {
    title: state => get(state, `${this.section}.title`),
    message: state => get(state, `${this.section}.message`),
  })
}
</script>
```

The problem is, it seems the props are undefined at the time when `mapState()` is executed. If I hardcode the prop values, the component works. Also, if I log the props in the `created()` hook, I get the expected values. So it seems like a race condition.

Am I going about this the wrong way here?

**Update**

The module namespace must be passed from within the mapping function, like so:

```js
computed: mapState({
  title() {
    return get(this.$store.state, `${this.module}.${this.section}.title`);
  },
  message() {
    return get(this.$store.state, `${this.module}.${this.section}.message`);
  }
})
```

(note that `get()` is a lodash, not a vue function)

This can be further abstracted into a mixin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the comment in the [`mapState example`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html#the-mapstate-helper):

> ```
> // to access local state with `this`, a normal function must be used
> countPlusLocalState (state) {
>   return state.count + this.localCount
> }
> ```

You are using arrow functions.

As for `this.module`, I think you're going to have to forego the [binding helper notation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace) and explicitly put the module reference into the definitions. I'm guessing that looks like:

```
computed: mapState(this.module, {
  title(state) {
    return get(`${state}.${this.module}`, `${this.section}.title`);
  },
  message(state) {
    return get(`${state}.${this.module}`, `${this.section}.message`);
  }
})
```

Comment: Missed that, thanks. Now I only need to be able to access `this.module` in the `mapState()` call. Any ideas?

Comment: That's the way I'm doing it for now, but for the size of application I'm working on, it's gonna get really verbose :( thx anyway

Comment: Thought about it again, of course `this.module` could be used within the binding helpers as well, it's just not quite as convenient as supplying it only once. Updated my question with the solution. Thanks again for pointing it out.